# Changing NSDocument tab names. (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, webkit, wkwebview, nsdocument

I am building a browser in xcode and am struggling with setting up dynamic tab titles based on the webpage titles, I am somewhat of a beginner, and have built this entire project essentially using stackoverflow.

**The Problem:**

Currently, all tabs are named after the window controller, if I change its name in storyboard, the tab names change but every method I have tried to use in order to display the webpage title has failed.

[Screenshot when window controller title is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItVfg.png)

[Screenshot when window controller title is filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlRr6.png) (This One is useful for identifying issue)

As I am a beginner, I would appreciate if you explained the problem or solution to what I am trying to achieve **in detail.**

*If this is a duplicate please provide a link to the near exact clone question.*

Comment: Are the tabs tabbed windows? Is the window controller owned by the document?

Comment: @Willeke I'm not totally sure how to do that. Is there a guide online?

Comment: What does NSDocument have to do with the question? Is the app document-based? Are the tabs document windows?